# Selenium image not loaded

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Please help me solve the problem with running on a remote server (server at digitalocean) selenium.

What a question. With selenium I want to test my website. Everything works well, but there is one problem. I have a static page with a CAPTCHA, where I take off the user if it is too active. When selenium redirected to this page, the image itself does not show the captcha. Obtain image asynchronously. In Selenium enabled Javascript. If it does not run on a remote server, and on my computer, then you can see the captcha. In order to run on the server GUI programs (firefox) using xvfb. I need to be firmly confident that the CAPTCHA is shown as I plan to add more rules to check whether the user is a human, and each time it does not have to run the tests themselves, they would monitor the server side and overthrown me results.

isVisibility triggered even if the image is "broken."

If anyone encountered this problem or a clue what could be the reason, please tell me and I'll try to implement.

Comment: It's a little hard to follow.  Would you please provide a server example of what happens next to a local example for what the exact difference is? My best guess at what you are saying is that you want to compare two captcha images...

Comment: @mutt, thank you for your comment. I want to make sure that the CAPTCHA displayed to the user. 

A check is made very simple. In image CAPTCHA is a class `.c-img`. I'm trying to find an element with this class. If it is, then check it for visibility. If it is visible, then the CAPTCHA displayed.

When I run the tests on the local machine, I can see that the CAPTCHA is shown. When I run the tests on a remote server instead of CAPTCHAs shown here is a picture: 

![](http://69.39.239.48/5014/140419430236110.jpg) 

but all the other pictures are displayed. Ie in this case, not shown CAPTCHA.

Comment: Are all the browser settings the same between the remote and local machines?  Same OS as well or different?  Can you log onto the server and execute it locally there and get the same result as on your machine?